# Creating two Titles for a same chart using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-charts

I have a chart where I have created chart title using a cell reference.
My code is given below:

```
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart001").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Caption = "=New_pivot!$B$1:$B$3"
```

Here I have a chart with a dynamic title from a pivot table range B1:B3.
I want to add one more title in my chart using a reference from pivot table reference cell B4 and also want to color the same in red in my chart(only B4 value).
I am not so sure how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First set the title to the full range (B1:B4). Then color only the characters that need the coloring, based on the length of the strings.

Code (executing against "ActiveSheet"):

```
Sub Test()
Dim noColorLength As Integer
Dim colorLength As Integer
Dim tr As TextFrame2
Dim r As Range

'Get the total length of the "not colored part"
For Each r In Range("B2:B4")
   noColorLength = noColorLength + Len(r.Value) + 1
Next r

'Get the length of the red part:
colorLength = Len(Range("B5").Value)


With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart001").Chart.ChartTitle
    'Set the caption:
    .Caption = "=Sheet1!R1C2:R4C2"

    'Color the caption, starting char is after the 1st three cells, red part has length of the 4th cell
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(noColorLength + 1, colorLength).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End With
End Sub
```

Note: This is coloring **part of the title**. Any chart only has 1 title, ever. As an alternative it is possible to add a shape / textbox with a second "title" that can be moved around / located elsewhere compared to the actual chart title.